# How to add a new list item before another specific list item with class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I need to add a new list item within the below UL but it needs to be before the last list item that has the `class="more"`.

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs sub-nav" >
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >AA</span>            
        </li>
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >BB</span>            
        </li>
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >CC</span>            
        </li>
        **<<< --- new list item entry to go here --- >>>**
        <li class="more" style="display: none;">
            <span>...</span>
            <ul id="overflow"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$("#nav-tabs ul").append('<li class="hor-menu"><span class="class-a" >DD</span></li>')
```

but am unsure how to insert it before the last li.more item.

Comment: didn't you mean `.nav-tabs ul` instead of `#nav-tabs ul`?

Comment: That looks right but still unsure how to inject before last li list item with the class-"more"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First option**

```
$('.more').before('<li class="hor-menu"><span class="class-a" >DD</span></li>');
```

**Second option**

First let's get the position of the `more` class.

```
var pos = $('nav-tabs > li').index($('.more'));
```

And then add it to the DOM

```
$('ul > li:eq('+pos+')')
    .before('<li class="hor-menu"><span class="class-a" >DD</span></li>');
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.before()` since OP wants new item to come _before_ the `li.more` item?

Comment: Just letting you know that your first option worked but did notice that you edited your answer to be before. All good on that option, so thanks for that. Second option unfortunately did not work, when I tried it in codepen.io

Comment: Have used your first option and all working great. Thanks.

Comment: @tonyf You're welcome. Second option works now but if you can use the first option, you should, because it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:last` pseudo selector like this to select the last element of a set

```
$("li.more:last")
```

then you can use `before` to insert it before the last li more item.

```
$("li.more:last").before('<li class="hor-menu"><span class="class-a" >DD</span></li>');
```

Here is a working JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mervinsamy/0n4g51hk/5/

I also added code snippet here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("li.more:last").before('<li class="hor-menu"><span class="class-a" >DD</span></li>');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs sub-nav" >
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >AA</span>            
        </li>
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >BB</span>            
        </li>
        <li class="hor-menu">
            <span class="class-a" >CC</span>            
        </li>
        <li class="more">
            <span>...</span>
            <ul id="overflow"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="more">
            <span>...</span>
            <ul id="overflow"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="more">
            <span>...</span>
            <ul id="overflow"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="more">
            <span>...</span>
            <ul id="overflow"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mervin for your answer and example.